# How does Chrome/Firefox/ie10+ handle cross protocol HTTP requests?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, xss

I've been writing a webpage that makes use of an online API that **only** outputs JSON, and is **only** served from an SSL server. (It's the Eventbrite API). And my personal web server does not support SSL.

When I use a jQuery HTTP GET request (I've also used straight AJAX, and XDomainRequest queries as well) for a response to parse into my webpage I get an error: [SCRIPT5: Access is denied](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Dn887953(v=VS.94).aspx). This only happens on IE9 and lower, all other browsers it runs fine.

Which brings me to the question, why did Microsoft implement this protection in IE9 and lower (and not 10+), and why does Google and Firefox not include such a protection. Is it the sand boxing Chrome/Firefox has that prevents potentially malicious scripts from running outside the browser? What is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Does Eventbrite support CORS? I believe this isn’t really about cross-protocol as much as it is about cross-domain.

Comment: @DanielB apparently it does support CORS. I'm not sure how that would help.